# Difference between casting/conversion methods in C#

Tags: c#

there are many ways to cast/convert object to another by what the difference between those and if there is no difference why there are so many ways to achieve one thing? Isn't that damage to language?

let's say object obj to string.

```
obj.ToString()
obj as string
(string)obj
Convert.ToString(obj)
```

Comment: Being able to make things in many ways is not damage. It is a powerful resource. Like in spoken languages: You can express yourself in various ways (which can have little nuance differences).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing different things here:

- obj.ToString() - this is a call to the `ToString()` method of the object. The object returns a string as it was programmed to.
- obj as string - this is an attempt to convert the object to a string, which may or may not fail (if it fails, the result is `null`), no exception will be thrown.
- (string)obj - this is an explicit cast of `obj` to the type `string`, you are telling the compiler that `obj` *is* a `string`. If `obj` is not a string type, you will get a cast exception.
- Convert.ToString(obj) - This is an explicit call to the Convert class to return a string representation of `obj`.

There are these many different ways to get a `string` from an `object` because each one is *different* and have subtle differences. Yes, in many cases the returned string will be the same, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: so forth type "creates" .ToString() even if this not exists?

Comment: @eugeneK - in .NET all objects inherit from `object`. Since `ToString()` is defined on it, all objects have a `ToString()` method, which could be overridden. As far as I know, `Convert.ToString(obj)` simply calls that, but essentially, what you are saying is right - `Convert` tries to "create" a string from an "object", as best it can.

Comment: @eugeneK, Convert.ToString uses the IConvertible interface of the type to determine how to perform the conversion.  This may have a different implementation than .ToString(), though often they will be the same.  It's also possible to look up a TypeConverter for a class and convert to string (if the converter supports it), which is the mechanism used by the designer when representing instances as strings in the property grid.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj as string
(string)obj
```

"as" operator is safe. if it cannot convert it returns null, when ()operator  raises exception

Comment: then why () exists at all? Exceptions are better to be handled before they occur in "right" programming. We can ask whether result value from obj as string == null and handle "exception".

Comment: @eugeneK "AS" operator works only with reference types. you cannot do it like this 
int r = stmng as int;
to ask the requeried type
you may call this  if(obj IS string)

Comment: @eugeneK, the explicit cast (rather than 'as') includes an assertion that you believe the cast will succeed. When you believe this to be the case, it makes sense to throw an exception if the cast fails.  Basically you explicitly cast when you couldn't meaningfully handle a cast failure if it did occur.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference:

- ToString is a method which relies on that the object itself defines what the string representation will look like.
- The [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(VS.71).aspx) keyword is reference conversion: `Note that the as operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions.`
- Using () to specify the type is an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(VS.71).aspx) whereas the as keyword is [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).
- Using the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(VS.71).aspx)-class actually just helps you parse it, the Convert.ToString probably just wraps .ToString() on the object.

Comment: what are reference and boxing conversions in three words?

Comment: @eugeneK, I don't know about three words, but check MSDN out on boxing /unboxing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are often several ways of doing basically the same thing, but with small variations. There is a distinct difference between casting and converting, where you for example can convert an `int` to `string`, but you can't cast an `int` to `string`.

You have a valid point in whether this is damaging for the language, but not mainly because there are many ways of doing things, but because they may be inconsistently implemented. When you implement classes, you have to be careful so that they behave as expected. Checking for equality is one example, where you can either use a method or an operator:

```
x == y
x.Equals(y)
```

If you implement one of them in your class but not the other, the compiler helps you with a warning that both has to be implemented for the class to behave properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, casting is very different from converting an object to a string. Casting is not converting an object into anything, it just assumes another type, whereas ToString really creates a string from an object (this may of course be a no-op if the object is already a string).

There are two casting operations for the reason Arseny explained: The `as` operator will return a null-reference whereas the `()` operator will raise an exception if the cast is not possible.

There are two ToString methods, as `obj.ToString()` of course only works if `obj` is really an object and not for instance an int. For the later case you have to use `Convert.ToString()`. Similarly, when `obj` is `null`, then `obj.ToString()` will raise an exception, whereas `Convert.ToString()` can return some sensible string (e.g. `"null"`).

Answer (score 1):

> what [is] the difference between those

There are 2 ways of type-casting and a range of classes and methods in the library. Typecasting is used for objects (values) that are already technically close and strongly related.

Conversion (the `Convert` class and `SomeType.Parse()` methods) are really converting datatypes (String to Int32 cannot be a cast).

> why there are so many ways to achieve
>   one thing?

Casting and Conversion are important, frequently used actions. That is why we have a fine-grained toolset, admittedly with quite a bit of overlap.