# Why can I use (string) but not "as string" in Linq to XML queries?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So I've been diving into Linq to XML for the first time (I know, I'm behind on the times) and so far it's pretty cool. However, I came across this *very* confusing behavior.

I'm parsing the common `.resx` format. In it, you have `data` tags that have a `value` and an optional `comment`. Here is the code I tried at first:

```
        var items = from str in doc.Root.Descendants("data")
            select new ResourceValue
            {
                Name = str.Attribute("name").Value,
                Value = str.Element("value").Value,
                Comment=str.Element("comment").Value
            };
```

Of course, where I get the `.value` of the `comment` element though, it throws a null reference exception.. Well, let's try again. I heard you can cast XElement to a string and it'll magically work. Let's try that

```
        var items = from str in doc.Root.Descendants("data")
            select new ResourceValue
            {
                Name = str.Attribute("name").Value,
                Value = str.Element("value").Value,
                Comment=str.Element("comment") as string
            };
```

Oooh. This time I get a compiler error.

> Cannot convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'string' via a
>   reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping
>   conversion, or null type conversion

Well, that's odd.. Let's search stackoverflow. Lo and behold, I find a snippet that suggests this instead:

```
        var items = from str in doc.Root.Descendants("data")
            select new ResourceValue
            {
                Name = str.Attribute("name").Value,
                Value = str.Element("value").Value,
                Comment=(string)str.Element("comment")
            };
```

Whoa. That works!? But, casting `null` to string throws a null reference exception... doesn't it? I thought `as string` was **exactly** for this situation!?

How does this work, and why can I do an explicit cast, but not an explicit `as` cast?

Answer (score 9):

```
str.Element("comment") as string
```

This checks if `XElement` is a string. But it's not true - `XElement` is not derived from string, so it is not a string. That's why you have error.

```
(string)str.Element("comment")
```

This is an overloaded operator, which gets `Value` property internally:

```
public static explicit operator string(XElement element)
{
    if (element == null)        
        return null;

    return element.Value;
}
```

It first checks if operand is `null` and just returns `null` if so. That's why you don't have exception.

---

**BTW** there is interesting thing with these explicit casting operators - none of them will throw `NullReferenceException` because they check element for null before accessing it's Value property. Even if element is `null` and you are trying to get integer, then you will have `ArgumentNullException` instead of `NullReferenceException`. And if `null` is acceptable value for type you are casting to (i.e. nullable types or string) then `null` is returned without any exceptions. That's why using these explicit casting operators is much safer than accessing Value property.

Comment: So it's not calling the `ToString()` method implicitly?

Comment: @TheSolution nope, it just gets value if element is not null

Answer (score 0):

obj as string - this is an attempt to convert the object to a string, which may or may not fail (if it fails, the result is null), no exception will be thrown.
(string)obj - this is an explicit cast of obj to the type string, you are telling the compiler that obj is a string. If obj is not a string type, you will get a cast exception.

Refer this link for further insight.-
[Difference between casting/conversion methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178289/difference-between-casting-conversion-methods-in-c-sharp)